# Password text Field

Tags: java, android, variables, passwords

I am doing a project for class where I would like to create a little password login in Android Studio. I want to create something simple and I know how to do it on Java but I don't know how I would go about doing it in this application. I basically want to get up a password box and a button. On down of the button I would like to test the input of the edit text password box to see if it equals the variable. This variable would be set and definite to something like root. I need to find a way to test that output on the password field to see if it equals the variable. If it does then it would move to another page. The code will be below

my Java file:

```
package com.example.murdocbgould.passwordpt4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String passwordA = "root";
    }
}
```

my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.murdocbgould.passwordpt4.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="85dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="260dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password:"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="226dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="437dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="328dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:text="Bluetooth Texting Login"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="28dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="147dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here getting text from edittest and compare on button click if it matches than go to another activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final String passwordA = "root";

            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

               textView2.setText(editText.getText().toString().trim());
                    if(editText.getText().toString().trim().equals(passwordA)){
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                    // Do what you want when password is not matches.
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey,
Is there a specific Package I need for this? Its showing up with a few errors but is by far the best answer i've seen so far.
Thanks

Comment: No you dont need any external packages. It will automatically get needed package for TextView or Button etc.. Which error it shows? can you share?

Comment: Yes you have to just import some file. For that just go to red word and than hold alt and press enter than it show to import than hit enter on that. Do like this on all words..

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Now however my problem is that everything is piled on top of each other in the emulator. Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: For that you can use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout

Comment: Hello Again, This has worked perfectly but now as I am advancing I am having some problems with an error system. I feel like my problem is more a personal error however and would not be suitable for a new problem to be posted. Would you be able to continue to help me here in the comment section?

Comment: I can but that is not proper way according to stackoverflow. So you can contact me through another medium. Definitely I will help you.

Comment: Which way would be most convenient for me to contact you with?

Comment: I posted it as another post if you go to my profile and look at the question

Comment: Okey.. Its very good to post another question. Never mind to ask any question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the input from the `EditText` and compare it with the password variable in `onClick` of the button.

```
//Making reference of edittext. 
EditText etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText)

// setting onclick to Button.
((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
 // checking the required condition.                       
 if(etPassword.getText().toString().trim().equal(YOUR_PASSWORD_VARIABLE))
                    {
                     //PASSWORD MATCHES
                    }else
                    {
                     //PASSWORD MISSMATCHE
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to reference your buttons in the java code and then you have to get references to all the necessary textfields too, see the simple implementation below:

```
package com.example.murdocbgould.passwordpt4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //make references to your edittext and buttons in the activity_main.xml
            EditText passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            String passwordA = "root";

            //listen for button clicks here
            submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
            //compare your password with password and continue

            //if you wish to move to another page (which I assume is an activity), edit the next line
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
                                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (editText.getText().toString().equals(passwordA)){
                startActivity(new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class));
            }  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (editText.getText().toString().equals(passwordA)){
                startActivity(new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class));
            }else{
              //Pasword Not Match
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Button mBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
      if (editText.getText().toString().equals(passwordA)){
            startActivity(new Intent(this,AnotherActivity.class));
       }  
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

               textView.setText(editText.getText().toString().trim());
                    if(editText.getText().toString().trim().equals(passwordA)){
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                       //  Show the user as a Toast that the password is incorrect. 
                    }
                }
            });
```