# Run time permission for WRITE_External_STORAGE when Downloading a file from application.?

Tags: android, webview, android-permissions

can Anyone help me  in asking run time permission for `WRITE_External_STORAGE` when i m downloading a file from my application.? Using my `Webview` in android which display my website that i have PDF files in that so i require run-time permission to allow storage access in my app..

Here is my sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://learntatatrusts.org/");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String 
        contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {


            DownloadManager.Request request = new 
            DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            String cookie = 
            cookieManager.getCookie("https://learntatatrusts.org/");
            request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath(); //which returns 
            the internal app files directory path

            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.
            VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.
            DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) 
            getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add this line  to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Than check permission on create permission is already granted or not if already granted than simply load your url and if not that ask for permission.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

 // Function for check permission already granted or not 
    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 //  Permission check
        if (!hasPermissions(context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE})) {
        // Permission ask
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 111);
        } else {
// if permission is already granted than load url
            loadUrl();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void loadUrl() {
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://learntatatrusts.org/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String
                    contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {


                DownloadManager.Request request = new
                        DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                String cookie =
                        cookieManager.getCookie("https://learntatatrusts.org/");
                request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath(); //which returns the internal app files directory path

                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.
                        VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.
                        DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)
                        getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 111) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                loadUrl();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hey thnk u for helping but i m getting red mark to context this place if (!hasPermissions(context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}))

Comment: plse help me with this.?

Comment: hey code is working nice bro nd thnk  u for help..!!

Comment: Have you solved red mark?? if not than 
Read these comment
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940023/password-text-field/45940252#45940252

Comment: yea i have solved all the problems and thnk u for help..!!